# I am using “Hindi and Gujrati” font then I am getting “Black Squre Dots”?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, .net, php

At the time of generating PDF file when I am using “Hindi and Gujrati” font then I am getting “Black Squre Dots”. Below I am using code. Here I am trying to convert in UTF-8 but it’s not converting.

```
file_path_PDF_new="C:\example\hello.pdf"
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(file_path_PDF_new,pagesize=letter, rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72, topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18, encoding='utf-8')
Notice = "नमस्ते दुनिया"
new_Notice=Notice.decode('utf-8')
styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
ptext = '<font size=12>%s</font>' % new_Notice

Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
```

doc.build(Story)
[image]

Comment: Sometimes I get similar issues if I am viewing  a pdf and I don't have that particular font in my system. To get around this issue, we use usually save the font within the actual pdf. Most print to pdf printing should have this ability, but I could not tell you how to code this. Not sure if this is the actual issue, but  I thought I would share.

Comment: Can i install  “Hindi and Gujrati” font in my system?

Comment: If you Google "print to pdf created black squares", you should get posts with similar problems and solutions. This [link](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/pdf-files-has-little-squares.610083/) is an example to my first comment. Unfortunately this is all I can think of that might be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by TsvGis, you'll probably need to embed the font in the document.

You appear to be using reportlab for this, check the FAQ on their site, [they have an example of how to embed fonts](http://www.reportlab.com/documentation/faq/) - section 2.6.2

Be aware that there might be licensing issues on some commercial fonts (they may not embed properly).

If this is the case there are plenty of free fonts with the Gujarati code block, or you could look into whether this library supports outlining (replacing text with the vector shapes of letters.. but this makes your PDF much larger)